# Visual Studio Add-in: How to get selected items in window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

Let a "Breakpoints" window (by default opened by Debug>Windows>Breakpoints [ctrl+B, D]) serve as an example. Basically I select few breakpoints in it and I would like to know in my add-in which elements in this window are selected. I am aware that I can get [collection of breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.debugger.breakpoints.aspx) in project but I would like to know what elements are selected in "Breakpoints" window.

**"Is it possible to get selected items in window or even access its content at all?**"



Also I am not sure whenever or not should I post a separate question for this but is there actually a way to capture user activity in IDE like for example capturing an event when user sets (adds) a breakpoint?

<sup><sub>*Originally I also asked if is it possible to achieve certain things in Visual Studio Express Edition. But this part is irrevelant.*</sub></sup>

---

### Conclusion:

<sup>(after reading jessehouwing's answer)</sup>

I guess it is **not** possible using an Add-ins. Use VSPackages isntead. Also Add-ins are deprecated as of Visual Studio 2013 version.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to work around limitations in the Visual Studio Express edition. Visual Studio Express doesn't support nor *allow* extensibility by 3rd parties. So what you're trying to do, is against the license agreement.

Comment: You'll need to get a license for Visual Studio Professional, which comes with most of the features you seem to be needing. A quick search on ebay, amazon and other locations shows that you can buy a license for as low as $150.

Comment: No, Debugger.Break is withing license agreement. You're not extending Visual Studio in that case.

Comment: Aw.. I'm soory I've deleted my comments because you posted your answer and I wanted to read it before... I didn't suspect you would reply so soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, what you're trying to accomplish is explicitly prohibited in the Visual Studio Express edition and is a violation of it's license. To extend the product, you need to have at least Visual Studio Professional Edition. many of the extensibility points will actively refuse any communication with 3rd party add-ins.

Almost all the things you're asking are possible using Visual Studio Extensibility once you've installed the professional edition. Products like [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com/) show that almost everything is possible. Remember that most features inside visual studio are themselves extensions of the product.

Your question, indeed a whole list of questions, is indeed not the way to ask something on StackOverflow. I can give you some pointers to the documentation, which you've probably already found, and maybe to some open source products that themselves extend parts of Visual Studio that can serve as examples, but from there you'll have to piece something together until you're able to ask more specific questions.

- [Events you can subscribe to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.events.aspx), the breakpoints are a CommandEvents I suspect.
- [Manipulating windows inside Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/keet1583.aspx)

Projects that extend the debugger that might serve as an example:

- [PyTools](http://pytools.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Python/Product/Debugger/) (debugger for Python inside Visual Studio)
- [Node.js tools for Visual studio](http://nodejstools.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Nodejs/Product/InteractiveWindow/) (extending the Immediate Window)

But there is no easy answer to your question that fits inside this window. I'd suggest you use a tool like Reflector to look at how Microsoft accomplishes certain things (most of Visual Studio Extensibility is written in .NET anyways) and to look at open source projects that extend visual studio behavior. There are quite a few out there on Codeplex.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish and how it's different from the Breakpoints features inside Visual Studio Professional and up.

I suggest you ask your question in the [Visual Studio Extensibility forums over on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=vsx), which is in a collaborative forum format, instead of a Q&A format, allowing people to answer your question bit by bit.

Comment: I'm sorry to interrogate you but a quick question that can help me clarify this and help me immensely to set on right track, I guess. Are the examples you provided using add-ins feature or VSPackage? I've read that a lot of tools in Visual Studio are written using VSPackage model but I do not know about them using add-in. VSPackage just seemed more intimidating to me and that's why I wanted you to clarify this before I dwell into it more than I am comfortable with. It just seems like I cannot achieve what I am after with just mere add-in but I might be wrong and this is why I asked.

Comment: I was aware of [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.events.aspx) but again it didn't seem to have event that coresponds to user setting new breakpoint in project. In fact it seems to have a limited set of events that I can subscribe to.

Comment: And when you said "many of the extensibility points will actively refuse any communication with 3rd party add-ins." you meant Visual Studio Express Edition or did you meant Visual Studio Professional Edition as well?

Comment: Also I can't vote up your answer even though it was already usesful to me... do I have to accept it right away or can I wait until I digest what you wrote to me? or should I actually remove this question since it does not fit StackOverflow style as you mentioned and probably won't be to much use for others? or maybe should I edit and strip down my question to fit with your answer?..or maybe something else? What would you suggest?

Comment: VSPackages are the preferred way to extend Visual Studio. The Add-ins are the old model and have some limitations.

Comment: Indeed Visual Studio Express will actively refuse extensibility. Professional and up will not for obvious reasons.

Comment: Oh and regarding [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/keet1583.aspx) I knew about it as well but I can't seem to find any window that correlate to a Breakpoints window. When I get this window in my-plugin it is of some type (forgot which one, I will update it when I can) but it seems to lack information I want. Namely almost everything there is null and I have just access to its submenu items via Controls property.

Comment: If you can strip it down to smaller questions that's better. Otherwise just leave it and it will probably be closed at some point. The information will stay and be available to others.